# Can we remove the [convert] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

The [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag on the main site is always ambiguous. Can we eliminate it?

[image]

Comment: looks like it was attempted last Feb. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78937/shouldnt-the-convert-tag-be-burninated?rq=1

Comment: Sorry about that, the Cabal failed to ensure that the tag remains dead.  We've had a few of those lately.  Sigh.  I, for one, vote for blacklisting it.  We were only able to keep it dead for a month before it slipped through the cracks again...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Burninated.

Also, I created [imagemagick-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick-convert) and synonymized the two, since per the previous discussion this seems to be the most common *legit* use for it. Hopefully the "how can I convert CSV to XML?" folks will notice when "imagemagick" appears below their questions...

---

Also burn...inated [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/converting).

Comment: You have far more faith in the blind tags-as-keywords crowd than I do.

Comment: A propos: [tag:converting]

Comment: @DanielFischer - that one should be burned too.

Comment: @DanielA.White Guess why I posted it. I hoped Shog9 would notice.

Comment: @Daniel: thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: The synonym isn't, IMO, a good idea. Most of the stuff tagged imagemagick-convert now seems to be people trying to just use "convert" badly.

Comment: The tag [seems to have reappeared](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/convert/info).

Comment: Gone again. @Xufox

Comment: It's on again, maybe we should blacklist?

Comment: That's done, @Braiam

Comment: The tag [seems to have reappeared](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/convert) again.